# How I can get dynamic variable by $_POST

Tags: php, dynamic, twig

I have something like :

```html
<fieldset>
  {% if clientFriend %} 
    {% set cfInfo = clientFriend.info() %} 
  {% endif %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="friendName" class="hidden"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FIO"
       name="friend[{{ cfInfo.id }}][name]"
       {% if cfInfo.friend_name %} value="{{ cfInfo.friend_name }}" {% endif %}>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phoneFriend" class="hidden"></label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone"
      name="friend[{{ cfInfo.id }}][phone]"
      {% if cfInfo.phone_friend %} value="{{ cfInfo.phone_friend }}" {% endif %}>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-outline-blue-sm">
         Add new 
     </button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

how can I get this dynamic variable by `$_POST`

```php
if ($_POST['friend[cfInfo.id][name]'])
```

unfortunately it doesn't work .

Comment: First do a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your script, to see how that gibberish is being transmitted. You will probably be able to figure it out from what you then see.

Comment: You could put `{{ cfInfo.id }}` into a hidden field and then use the value of that field to access the proper index of the `$_POST['friend']` array.  Or just use a loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: 1) in $_POST i have this one
Array ( [friend] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => New Test Client ) [1] => Array ( [phone] => +7-324-234-2342 ) ) )

2)I will have a lot of this clients, dynamicly, when user push the button "Add"